# Ensure exception coverage at compile time

Tags: ada

Is there a way to get GNAT to ensure all exception cases are handled?

To give an example:

```
   package IO renames Ada.Text_IO;
   package EIO renames Ada.IO_Exceptions;

   procedure Open_File (File : in out IO.File_Type) is
   begin
      IO.Open (File, IO.In_File, "example.txt");
   exception
      when EIO.Use_Error =>
         IO.Put_Line ("Use!");
      when EIO.Device_Error =>
         IO.Put_Line ("Device!");
   end Open_File;
```

`Open` can also raise `Name_Error` so I would like GNAT to warn that case has not been handled.

I found `pragma Restrictions (No_Exception_Propagation)` but that seems to apply the check to the standard library calls as well so `Open` becomes unusable because it propagates exceptions itself. If I apply this to my example, I get:

```
14:07: warning: pragma Restrictions (No_Exception_Propagation) in effect
14:07: warning: this handler can never be entered, and has been removed
16:07: warning: pragma Restrictions (No_Exception_Propagation) in effect
16:07: warning: this handler can never be entered, and has been removed
```

For an example of what I want from another language; Nim has a `raises` pragma to annotate what exceptions a procedure can raise, which the compiler enforces. The list can be empty, ie. `raises: []`, and the compiler will require that all exceptions will be handled and not propagate. Is there an equivalent to this in Ada?

Comment: Using SPARK, you can guarantee all exceptions are handled in SPARK-verified sections of your program, by proving that none will ever be raised...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible in Ada.

Nim is able to do it because the `raises` pragma is part of the function signature. Therefore, for any call, it is statically known which exceptions can be raised. This is not the case in Ada.

If you argue that the compiler could implicitly figure out which exceptions can be raised by any subroutine, that is true but does not solve the problem because Ada allows for both dispatching calls and function pointers. For both of these you don't know statically the function which will be called (without a pointer analysis anyway, which is out of scope for most compilers) and therefore can't know the exceptions that could be raised (since they are not part of the signature).

Comment: It isn’t really true that the compiler can figure out which exceptions could be raised. One of the contributors on c.l.a. points out that it’s always possible for `Storage_Error` to be raised (f.e. by stack overflow, which I doubt even SPARK can prevent)

Comment: @SimonWright That would just mean that the compiler tells you that `Storage_Error` can be raised on any operation that allocates (just like `Constraint_Error` could be raised by any division operation). This was more of a theoretical remark; the modular compilation model of Ada forbids propagation of such body-derived knowledge anyway since a compilation unit knows only the specification of other units. There are languages (e.g. Zig) that *do* treat `Storage_Error` as an error that is inferred and part of the signature.

Comment: Doesn’t have to be allocation, at least not from the heap: if you declare a string of length `Integer’Last`, it would be pleasing to get `Storage_Error` rather than a very obscure memory tramplement. Something like this happened to me because I thought that `Unchecked_Conversion` merely provided an alternate view of an object rather than creating a copy on the stack (this behaviour might be affected by the optimisation level)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to handle all available exceptions, you can use `when others` in `exception` section. Your example will look that:

```
package IO renames Ada.Text_IO;
package EIO renames Ada.IO_Exceptions;

procedure Open_File (File : in out IO.File_Type) is
begin
   IO.Open (File, IO.In_File, "example.txt");
exception
   when An_Exception : others =>
      IO.Put_Line (EIO.Exception_Message(An_Exception));
end Open_File;
```

If you want to handle each exception in a separated way, then you have to list each of exceptions separately (as in your example). But compiler will not warn you about missing handler of an exception.